# Unable to authenticate with Google token in Node JS

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

On a Node server, I am trying to validate a Google user but it always returns with a "Bad Request". What is wrong in my code?

```
var post_data = querystring.stringify({
    'alt': 'json',
    'access_token': <token from REST API params>
});

var post_options = {
    host: 'www.googleapis.com',
    port: '443',
    path: '/oauth2/v1/userinfo',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
    }
};

var post_req = https.request(post_options, function (result) {
    if (result.statusCode == 200) {
        result.on('data', function (chunk) {
            //Valid user stuff
        });
    }
    else {
        //Invalid user stuff
    }
});

post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.end();
```

The scenario here is that my client app is a chrome extension that successfully gets a token. The token is passed to my REST API hosted on the Node server. I try to replay that token to authenticate the Google user. (Note that if I use the token on the Chrome extension to make the same request, it succeeds and I get the profile information! It's only the request on the Node server that fails.) Help me! Please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are:

- Using the property `host` instead of `hostname`
- Providing the `port` parameter (not sure about this one, but it will work without it)
- Method should be `POST`, not `GET`

So, your new `post_options` object should be:

```
var post_options = {
    hostname: 'www.googleapis.com',
    path: '/oauth2/v1/userinfo',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
    }
};
```

If you want to make it easier on yourself you could use a module such as [google-auth-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library) or [google-sign-in](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-sign-in).